# Apache Netbeans Debug options inactive

Tags: javascript, debugging, netbeans, ide

I have a problem with the debug options in Apache Netbeans, all options are inactive.

[image: inactive buttons]

Comment: Can you try it with a previous version? Or did it already work in v12.0?

Comment: It is working, apparently it happens because the browser (chrome) already had a working debbuger